# Como gravar dados MYSQL em duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo

Tags: php, mysql

Como gravar dados MYSQL em duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo, porém a segunda tabela de nome "t_cadparcelas" deve inserir mais de um registro conforme o número de parcelas por isso implementei o for mas estou tendo erros de compilação, qual o melhor metodo para gravar estes registros?

Também é necessário capturar o último registro da tabela inserida um momento antes "t_cadcontratos" para que eu possa inserir na segunda tabela "t_cadparcelas".

**Conexão com banco de dados:**

```
    <?php include"../Connections/config.php";
    $conexao = mysqli_connect("$hostname_config","$username_config","$password_config", "$database_config");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Erro ao selecionar o banco de dados, por favor informe o administrador do sistema (suporte@emperiumcode.com) ou envie um email para contato@buchmannoptical.com.br !" . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

// Set autocommit to off
mysqli_autocommit($conexao,FALSE);
?>
```

**Insert's:**

```
<div id="painelcadastro2" align="center">
<?php   if (isset($_GET['cadastra']) && $_GET['cadastra'] == 'add') {
  $datacompra = implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/",$_GET['datacompra'])));
  $codigoProduto = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'identProduto1');
  $nomeProduto = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'nomeProduto1');
  $qtProduto = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'qtProduto1');
  $valorProduto = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'valorProduto1');
  $valorparc = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'valorparcela');
  $parcelas = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'select_parcelas');
  $entrada = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'entrada');
  $total = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'total');
  $nrFicha = filter_input(INPUT_GET,'cadastro');
  $status = "ativo";
  $dataVencimento = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'datasvenc');
  $dataVencimento = unserialize(base64_decode($dataVencimento));//Decode para array
  $pagamento = "CREDIARIO";
  $cadastracontratos = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO t_cadcontratos (Ficha, DataContrato, QuantParcelas, ValorContrato, Entrada, Saldo, DescricaoProduto, QuantProdutos, Vendedores, FormaPagamento) 
                          VALUES ('$nrFicha', '$datacompra', '$parcelas', '$valorProduto', '$entrada', '$total', '$nomeProduto', '$qtProduto', UPPER('$_SESSION[MM_Username]'), '$pagamento')");
  for($numparcelas=1; $numparcelas>$parcelas; $numparcelas++ ){
  $cadastraparcelas = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO t_cadparcelas (NumContrato, NumParcela, ValorParcela, DataVencimento, Status) 
                          VALUES ('$NumContrato', '$numparcelas', '$valorparc', '$dataVencimento[numparcelas]', '$status')");
  }
  if($cadastracontratos == '1' && $cadastraparcelas == '1') {
    // Commit transaction
mysqli_commit($conexao);
        echo "Venda Crediário realizada com sucesso !";
  }else{
        echo "Erro ao realizar a venda Crediário, tente novamente !";
  }
// Close connection
mysqli_close($conexao);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sim, você precisa no `loop` do `for`, utilizar o ID gerado pela última consulta.

```
$ultimoID = mysql_insert_id();
```

Sugiro para teste que você verifique para cada inserção na base, se ela foi bem sucedida, somando o numero de parcelas bem sucedidas e testando no final.

Agora tem algumas observações importantes:

- As funções MySQL no PHP serão descontinuadas, deverá utilizar o [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.pdo-mysql.php) ou [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php) ao invés de MySQL.
- O MySQLi não muda quase nada do que se usa no MySQL. Muda muito pouco, dê uma olhada.

Outra questão é:

- Não dá para confiar que todos os query`s executados pela inserção serão executados. Neste caso, você deve fazer uma transação (*transaction*), ou seja, inicia a transação, executa as queries, se alguma falhar, você dá um *rollback* em tudo. Assim não ficará com lixo na base e terá certeza que tudo está ok. Dê uma lida a respeito de [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html).

Comment: Rogerio, o conceito do site em relação à qualidade é de Wikipedia; ou seja, português formal e bem formatado. Posso editar sua resposta, mas prefiro deixar a dica neste caso. Temos um FAQ da comunidade para isso: [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/201) (acho que lá está mais focado em formatação, mas o bom PT é essencial;)

Comment: Sim, pode deixar. Tentei ajudar, pois a questao estava um pouco vaga. Vou tomar um maior cuidado na forma de redigir as respostas. Desculpe.

Comment: Bom, wikifiquei sua resposta.

Comment: Rogerio, será mesmo descontinuado o MYSQL? De qualquer forma alterei para MYSQLi na pergunta, agora em relação a teoria do transactions entendi, mas não achei exemplos, então tentei montar algo na resposta, seria isso? preciso de alguma lib em meu diretório? obrigado!

Comment: Sim, as funcoes Mysql no PHP serao descontinuadas. Sobre as transações (transactions). Veja um exemplo no link abaixo: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_commit.asp

Comment: Certo @RogerioCoelho alterei a pergunta e estou utilizando mysqli e transactions, mas estou com problemas no for, podes analisar a pergunta editar por gentiliza? Muito Grato!

Comment: Coloque o for assim: for($numparcelas=1; $numparcelas<=$parcelas; $numparcelas++ )